# How To: Migrate aspx (non-Razor) from MVC3 to MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

My shop is in the midst of upgrading our old website from MVC 3 to MVC 5. Most of the pages in the site are MVC Views running Angular, but a few of the older pages are MVC Views with View Models and unhappiness.

So we spent most of the day doing the upgrade, moving to MVC 5, and upgrading our Ninject to the latest, and everything seemed awesome until we opened one of the older pages, and got a nasty json serializer error. After some investigating, we found that we were just not going to be able to get the json serializtion to work, and that's no big deal as we can likely get the go-ahead to convert those pages to Angular, but there was one thing that really grabbed our attention: In the .aspx view, there is a bunch of "broken" red object text:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Bootstrap4.Base.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<BranchManagerViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" ID="tc" runat="server">
    Branch Management
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col px-0">
            <%  var isMobile = false;
                if (Session["IsMobile"] != null) { isMobile = (bool)Session["IsMobile"]; }

                if (isMobile == false) {  %>
                <div class="row recentAndCrumbs">
                    <div class="col-md-12 px-0 mx-0">
                        <ul class="breadcrumb" style="margin-bottom: 0; padding: 2px 15px 0 0;">
                            <%  var last = Model.Breadcrumb.Last();
                                foreach (var crumb in Model.Breadcrumb) { %>
```

In that chunk of stuff, these things are red and "broken":

- `ViewPage<BranchManagerViewModel>`
- `Session`
- `Model.`

But the page compiles, and works fine in the browser. It's just uneditable (easily) now, as you can't get intellisense on those things, or step into them. We assume that some things are changed in the move from MVC 3 to 5, but we can't figure out how to get these references working again. (And nope, we're not a Razor shop... so any help needs to be just old-school .Net MVC.)

Visual of the above code:

[image]

I would greatly appreciate help in getting those things away from red, un-usable, references and objects, back to their happy, intellisensed, selves.

Thanks!

Comment: When we did a similar conversion years ago those references never recovered. When views compiled and site was deployed, everything worked just fine, though, but intellisense was, indeed, gone.

Comment: @zaitsman - I'm honestly hoping to just learn what the new syntax is, so I can repair them, but everywhere I look, I see nothing but Razor examples, which isn't what I'm looking for, sadly.

Comment: Though with some further research, I see that Razor has sadly become the "norm" with ASP.Net MVC 5, so I guess it's time to dust off the internet and do some learning.